# Change treeview scroll position thru PowerScript

Tags: powerbuilder

How can I change Treeview Scroll Position thru PowerScript?
Im thinking to synchronize Scroll position of a datawindow and treeview but I cant seem to get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the `send()` command using a handle to the treeview, the event id (vscroll = 277), a flag to tell it HOW to scroll (up one line, down one line, up a page, down a page, etc), and then one more long value which is an identifier for a string or message (not used here)

So, to scroll up one line you would use:

```
Send(Handle(tv_1), 277, 0, 0)
```

and to scroll down one line,  you would use:

```
Send(Handle(tv_1), 277, 1, 0)
```

Then use the datawindow's `scrollvertical` event to keep them in sync.

Hope that helps.